# Symfony 2.8.4: No mapping file found named 'Post.orm.yml' for class

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

i'm using Symfony 2.8.4 with MySql. (Java  version: 1.8)

i have created this class: Post.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="symfony_demo_post")
 *

 */
class Post
{

    const NUM_ITEMS = 10;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $slug;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="post.blank_content")
     * @Assert\Length(min = "10", minMessage = "post.too_short_content")
     */
    private $content;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }



}
```

and when i try to generate this entity via console  `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Post`
i get this error :

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
Class "AppBundle\Entity\Post" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

and in the browser i get: `No mapping file found named 'Post.orm.yml' for class`
 How can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you have the comment in this format:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="symfony_demo_post")
 *

 */
```

This should be

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="symfony_demo_post")
 */
```

Note the blank line...

Also, if the error is being produced using a controller, keep in mind that the way you have to call the repository is

```
$postRepo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post');
```

instead of

```
$postRepo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:PostRepository');
```

That is what happened to me 5 minutes ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the mapping type in your config to 'annotation' since it seems that you are using that.